# Can I make an ACL in squid for transparent connections?

Tags: proxy, squid, access-control-list, transparent-proxy, http-proxy

I have a squid proxy that transparently intercepts connections from an internal network, and is explicit for connections from another network.

I want to use authentication for the external network, and allow any connection from the internal network.

Is there an ACL for transparently intercepted connections that I can use to specify this?